# Enviar archivo en mail con Django

Tags: django, email

Tengo un formulario que manda los datos por email.

Quiero que tambien se envien los archivos por el mail pero no se como.

Dejo la vista y el template.

```
def sendMail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        template = render_to_string('email_template.html', {
            'first_name':request.POST['first_name'],
            'last_name':request.POST['last_name'],
            'phone':request.POST['phone'],
            'city':request.POST['city'],
            'state':request.POST['state'],
            'birthday':request.POST['birthday'],
            'sexo':request.POST['sexo'],
            'subject':request.POST['subject'],
            'hijos':request.POST['hijos'],
            'email':request.POST['email'],
            'message':request.POST['message'],
        })

        email = EmailMessage(
            request.POST['subject'],
            template,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['mail...']
        )

        email.fail_silenty=False
        email.send()

    return render(request, 'send_email.html')
```

El template es un form con todos los inputs.

Por ahora funciona perfecto, se mandan los datos todo pero me falta lo del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

La idea era pasar varios archivos.

La solucion fue la siguiente:

```
if request.FILES:
        uploaded_file = request.FILES
        for file in uploaded_file.getlist('file'):
            email.attach(file.name, file.read(), file.content_type)
```